# add option to python tkinter optionmenu and execute a function when selected

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

Here is a much simplified version of what I was trying to do.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

n = 1

def show1():
    print var.get()

def add1():
    global n
    l = 'Option %d' % n
    n += 1
    op['menu'].add_command(label=l,command=tk._setit(var,l))
    var.set(l)
    print 'added %s' % l

var = tk.StringVar()
op = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,[], command=show1)
op.pack()
tk.Button(root,text='add 1', command=add1).pack()
tk.Button(root,text='show', command=show1).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The 'add 1' button successfully adds options to the option menu.
Clicking on an option does not call the show1 routine, you have to click on the 'show' button.

-------Original Question-----

I'm trying to read in a number of selected files and save information about each of them.

As I read them in the file base name is stored in the option list.  That seems to be working.

I would like to show the saved information when I click on a selection in the option menu. That is not working.

The code below is adding name to the option list, but you have to click the 'Get it' button to show the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter as tk
import os,sys
import tkFileDialog as tkfd

class E(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.files = {}
        self.statusMsg = tk.StringVar()
        self.nLines    = tk.StringVar()
        self.maxLine   = tk.StringVar()
        self.fileName  = tk.StringVar()

        tk.Button(self,text='Get a file',command=self.openfile, bd=5).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.fileOption = tk.OptionMenu(self,self.fileName, [], command=self.getIt)
        self.fileOption.configure(width=10, bd=5, relief='ridge')
        self.fileOption.grid(row=2, column=0)
        tk.Label(self,text='Line Count').grid(row=3, column=0)
        tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.nLines).grid(row=3, column = 1)
        tk.Label(self,text='Max Line').grid(row=4, column=0)
        tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.maxLine).grid(row=4, column = 1)
        tk.Button(self,text='show file',command=self.getIt, bd=5).grid(row=5)
        tk.Label(self,text='Status').grid(row=6, column=0)
        tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.statusMsg,width=20).grid(row=6, column = 1)

    def openfile(self):
        textFile = tkfd.askopenfile(mode='r', defaultextension='.txt',
                                    filetypes=[("text","*.txt"),("All Files","*")],
                                    initialdir='.')
        (fileBaseName, fileExt) = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(textFile.name))
        maxLength = -1
        lineCount = 0
        for line in textFile:
            lineCount += 1
            maxLength = max(maxLength,len(line))
        self.files[fileBaseName] = [maxLength,lineCount]
        self.nLines.set(lineCount)
        self.maxLine.set(maxLength)
        self.statusMsg.set('Opened %s' % fileBaseName)

        """ This works to add the file but the command is not 
        executed when selected in the optionmenu """
        self.fileOption['menu'].add_command(label=fileBaseName, command=tk._setit(self.fileName,fileBaseName))
        self.fileName.set(fileBaseName)

        """
        fileList = sorted(self.files.keys())
        for fname in fileList:
            self.fileOption['menu'].add_command(label=fname, command=lambda v=fileList: self.getIt)
        """
        """
        self.fileOption = tk.OptionMenu(self,self.fileName, fileList, command=self.getIt)
        print fileList
        """
        """
        self.fileOption['menu'].add_command(label=fileBaseName, command=tk._setit(self.fileName,fileBaseName))
        self.fileOption.configure(command=self.getIt)
        """
        """
        self.fileOption['menu'].add_command(label=fileBaseName, command=self.getIt)
        """
        self.fileName.set(fileBaseName)

    def getIt(self):
        [maxLength,lineCount] = self.files[self.fileName.get()]
        self.nLines.set(lineCount)
        self.maxLine.set(maxLength)
        self.statusMsg.set('got it')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = E()
    #app.title('Build Roof')
    app.mainloop()
```

The comments show other things I've tried.

There are numerous examples of adding items to the option list and others that set the command, but none that do both.

P.S. I'd like to get rid of the pesky first blank entry in the option list

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be pretty simple.  It works with a grid layout.  Just leave an empty space where the OptionMenu needs to go and append new entries to a list.  Then create a new OptionMenu as you add entries.

The OptionMenu doesn't even appear until you have at least one entry.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

n = 1
vars=[]

def show1(*entry):
    print var.get()

def add1():
    global n
    l = 'Option %d' % n
    n += 1
    vars.append(l)
    op = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,*vars, command=show1).grid(row=0, column=1)
    var.set(l)
    print 'added %s' % l

var = tk.StringVar() 
root.grid()

tk.Button(root,text='add 1', command=add1).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root,text='   ', width=12).grid(row=0,column=1)
```

The Label in the last line doesn't need to be there if you have enough other things in the grid to keep the space open